# Logistics Regression & SVC: Do we need to do scaling if features are BOW, tf-idf or doc2Vec?

Tags: svm, logistic-regression, scaling, doc2vec

I know Logistics Regression & SVC usually require scaling of the features. However, if the features are generated by

1. BOW
2. tf-idf
3. doc2Vec

do we still need to scale the features?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You never *need* to do anything, but you should try it both ways, and choose the approach that scores better for your data & goals.

Comment: Thanks for yr reply! But I wish to understand why I need to or need not scale the features. Eg tf-idf by itself is regarded as scaling too, so do I need to use say standard scaler to scale it?

Comment: When you try different scalers, which works best? Only after deterimining that does it make sense to start investigating "why" scaling, or a particular kind of scaling, might help.